# MySQL Query Optimization - (need it without joins)

Tags: mysql, sql

I've following query to process using joins. Is there any alternative instead of using these counts and joins ?

```
select 
    ipd.data_city as city,
    count(distinct f.dim_ipinfo_id) as visitors, 
    count(distinct f.dim_visit_id) as visits,
    count(f.dim_Pageview_id) as pageviews
from fact_table f
left join dim_data ipd on ipd.dim_data_id = f.dim_data_id
where f.dim_member_id = 725
group by city
```

Comment: How long does it take right now? What's your expectation query time with the largest possible number of data?

Comment: Why not use JOINs? Is it an interview question?

Comment: it takes 30 seconds to execute and I have over 10 million of data rows to run this query on.

Answer (score 1):

It is not easy to understand whithout knowing your aim and the data structure.
However at a first glance the *JOIN* seems **necessary** because the grouping is done on the *city* field which seems to be on the *dim_data* table.
If you have a field referring to the city on the *fact_table* data you could use it for the grouping and remove the join, if not you have to stick with it.
Also, if you do not need the grouping on the city you could avoid the join, but id doesn't seems the case.